# How do I get intellisense/code-completion working in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I've been working with vscode for quite sometime now but I can never get the intellisense to work the way it does in fully featured IDE's or even how it is portrayed in videos. I created a simple repo. https://github.com/dwayne-roberts/vscode-code-completion-test/tree/master/src

And if you check the screenshots I just cannot get it to work.

[image]

It doesn't offer the methods or properties on the class. Only way I can seem to get it to work is to import the class directly.

Can anyone shine some light on this conundrum. I'm convinced it should be able to work this way.

Comment: What extensions have you installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, VS Code fails to load IntelliSense, maybe you installed an extension or changed the settings.json file.

Anyways, to solve this problem:

1. Restart VS Code
2. Install this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
3. Check with some code

The above extension adds more features to the current IntelliSense (AI) and can re-enable IntelliSense.

Comment: I already had that plugin installed. It seemed that the way I import modules seemed to matter. i always use a `jsconfig.js` and set my `baseUrl` to _src/_ I can then use import paths relative to my _src_ directory. But it seems vscode is not resolving that properly. I cannot follow those links to definition for instance. Only when I use url's relative to the current folder does it all work properly. :-\

Comment: @Dwayne using a jsconfig.js file to load imports is not necessary. If your problem still persists, try re-installing vscode. By the way, what extensions de you have installed?